# Julia @threads single

Tags: multithreading, julia

Is there something in Julia Threads similar to a `single` command in OpenMP that will ensure all threads wait before a particular block of code and then execute that block in only one thread? I have a loop that distributes calculations of forces between threads before performing an update to all locations at once, and I cannot find any feature to achieve this without terminating the `@threads` loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use locks:

```
function f()
    l = Threads.SpinLock()
    x = 0
    Threads.@threads for i in 1:10^7
        Threads.lock(l)
        x += 1  # this block is executed only in one thread
        Threads.unlock(l)
    end
    return x
end
```

Note that the `SpinLock` mechanism is dedicated to non-blocking codes (that is computations only, no I/O in the loop). If there is I/O involved `ReentrantLock` should be used instead.